# Using 2 ItemsControl to alternate between the way items are shown

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

On a Windows phone project im working on i need to have a page that has a list of items from the same class and it should appear as something like

> Image - Text
>   Text - Image
>   Image - Text
>   Text - Image
>   Image - Text
>   Text - Image

```
<ScrollViewer Name="NoticiasScroll" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,38,0,0">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="items" Height="653">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid Height="218" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Width="440" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Name="NewsImg" Source="/Assets/Images/pipa.png" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding titulo}"  Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="200" Margin="0,10,10,0" FontSize="28" FontFamily="Helvetica" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding texto}" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Helvetica" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="22,0,8,0" Width="190"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>


    </ScrollViewer>
```

right now i have this, but this way all the items appear with the same format. How can i make it so they alternate between two formats?

Comment: you could try to set the `Datatemplates`  in your `ItemsColtrol.Resources`

Comment: How would i alternate between them after?

Comment: `<DataTemplate DataType="{ local:YourType1}"> .... <DataTemplate DataType="{ local:YourType2}">...` and it should wire up automatically ( _if it doesn't work you need to set an ContentPresenter as ItemsTemplate_)

Comment: in my case all the items are from the same class, that wouldnt work in that case right?

Comment: @WiiMaxx has a point, you should do something similar to http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/08/06/multiple-item-templates-in-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: @Ric Ohh thats right. so maybe you cloud use a [ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) or an [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) i haven't use any of them so i can't help you further

Comment: @See Sharp, Thanks for the Link, i managed to solve my problem with it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your class which is bound to the ItemsControl with 2 Visibility properties.

```
public class MyItem
{
    public Visibility ShowEven { get; set; }
    public Visibility ShowOdd { get; set; }

    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Texto { get; set; }
}
```

Set alternating visibilities:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myItems.Count; i++)
{
    bool isEven = i % 2 == 0;

    myItems[i].ShowEven = isEven ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    myItems[i].ShowOdd = isEven ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
}

items.ItemsSource = myItems;
```

Use 2 grids inside your ItemTemplate that are bound to the visibility properties.

```
<ItemsControl Name="items">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid Visibility="{Binding ShowEven}" Background="Blue">
                        <Image />
                        <Image />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Visibility="{Binding ShowOdd}" Background="Red">
                        <TextBlock />
                        <TextBlock />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```